# Salesforce Heap with lists

Tags: apex, heap

I was writing a method in which i wanted to see if a value was in a specified list, instead of writing out if a==x || a==y || a==z if figured it would be shorter and cleaner to just do a list contains. I stumbled on something that puzzled me about apex.

```
Id id1 = '012i0000001ANtCAAW';
System.debug((new List<Id>{'012i0000001ANtCAAW', '012i0000001AdHDAA0', '0120H000001EYLaQAO'}).contains(id1));
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>{'012i0000001ANtCAAW', '012i0000001AdHDAA0', '0120H000001EYLaQAO'};
System.debug(ids.contains(id1));
```

The first debug statement results in false, while the second debug results in true. Now the list in the first must be on the heap otherwise I would not be able to reference its instance method.

Comment: Your post doesn't actually contain a question. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: There is a bug in List.contains for ID data-type. Use List<String> instead or Set<Id>

Comment: Sorry about the confusion @AdrianLarson, the question would be this behavior is not the behavior I would expect. I had not known this was a duplicate question so I thank everyone for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, but the format here is *question* and *answer*. You have made a statement rather than asking something.

Comment: I should of mentioned that the behavior in the marked duplicate was not exactly the behavior I was experiencing.. Assigning the reference to a variable the contains method was working, however not storing the reference to a variable the bug was active.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I will work on that for future questions for sure, thank you. I will say in my own defense I had no idea that this would of been a bug, I was struggling to understand what kind of question this would be. To me it seemed more like some kind of runtime memory assignment issue if anything for lack of a better description

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running into this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AT9cQAG) or some variant. At this time, `List<T>.contains` and `Set<T>.contains` behave inconsistently with the `Id` type.